# How to overcome the stale element reference error in my program

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am getting the Stale element error. I tried to overcome it but failed every time .

```
d.get("https://iaeme.com/ijciet/index.asp");
java.util.List<WebElement>link = d.findElements(By.className("lik"));
for (int k=1 ; k<= link.size();k++) {
    link.get(k).click();// stale element error goes here.
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println(d.getCurrentUrl());
}
```

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: What is the size of this List, which you have named as link?

Comment: Are you navigating away from the index page with the click for each link?

Comment: Size will differ , for this url the size is 52

Comment: @Grasshopper yes i am navigating away .

Comment: @DebanjanB sir  can u help

Comment: @sara once you navigate away to another page, you will get stale exception as the webelement from previous page cannot be found. Are you trying to test links in index page? Then you need to go back to the index page and search for the next link again. Keep a counter of the links initially and go increment.

Answer (score 0):

surround the exception throwing statement with a try block and catch the staleElementReferenceException.

```
d.get("https://iaeme.com/ijciet/index.asp");
 java.util.List<WebElement>link = d.findElements(By.className("lik"));
        for (int k=1 ; k<= link.size();k++) {
            try{
              link.get(k).click();// stale element error goes here.
             Thread.sleep(2000);
             System.out.println(d.getCurrentUrl());
           }catch(StaleElementReferenceException e){
              // find the element again OR handle the exception in your way
               }
        }
```

Other approach is to find element in each iteration. This will ensure the freshness of webElement after page navigation. 
Replace the statement

```
 link.get(k).click();
```

with this :

```
d.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='lik'])["+k+"]")).click();
```

Comment: This keeps printing -   System.out.println(d.getCurrentUrl()); again and again . what to do ?

Comment: This is just a generic code sample . You have to narrow down to the statement where staleElementReferenceException is raised.

Comment: Is there any other approach ??

Comment: Edited and added another approach in the answer.

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//*[@class='lik'])[3]"}     Gives this error

Comment: StaleElement reference is solved upto 2nd item. Debug & Locate from 3rd item in your list manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 d.get("https://iaeme.com/ijciet/index.asp");
 java.util.List<WebElement>link = d.findElements(By.className("lik"));
        for (int k=1 ; k<= link.size();k++) {
             if(link.get(k).isDisplayed()){
               link.get(k).click();// stale element error goes here.
               Thread.sleep(2000);
               System.out.println(d.getCurrentUrl());
             }
        }
```